# What's the preferred web server for perl?

Tags: perl, webserver

In PHP the best choice is nginx now,what's the case in perl world?

Comment: PHP generally (always?) runs as a FastCGI on NGINX. In this sense, you'd probably find that you got many of the advantages you get for PHP with PERL on NGINX. Check out http://wiki.nginx.org/EmbeddedPerlModule

Comment: Why is nginx best for PHP and what's 'best'? Nginx is good for serving static content and is often used as a reversed proxy.

Comment: @Aaron Newton ,so nginx is also the best choice for perl now?

Comment: Choose the best web server matching your requirements and use Plack/PSGI if i supports it, otherwise use FastCGI or proxy to a native Perl web server like Starman / Starlet or Twiggy.

Answer (score 8):

Nginx is still a fine choice, but if you write your Perl app to be [PSGI](http://plackperl.org/)-compliant, then you really shouldn't care; changing web servers is a snap.

Comment: I'm not looking for a fine choice,but best :)

Comment: "best" is heavily dependent on your requirements.. there is no "best" webserver.